# Why is this HTML code being rendered as one giant string instead of the code being evaluated?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

This code in a partial:

```
<div class ="vote_updated">
    <p><%= event.actor %> <% case event.subject.value
        when 1
            puts " upvoted"
        when -1
            puts " downvoted"
        when 0
            puts " removed a vote from"  
        end %> a song. </p>
    <div class="video_div">
        <%= render 'videos/video', :video => event.secondary_subject %>
    </div>
</div>
```

is being rendered as one big string instead of the resulting HTML code from the embedded ruby being evaluated.

This is the code that renders the partial:

```
<div id="feed_div">
    <%= render_timeline current_user.recent_events %>
</div>
```

and this is the `render_timeline` method in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def timeline(events)
  events.map do |event|
    render(:partial => "timeline_events/#{event.event_type}", :locals => {:event => event})
 end.join
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that your call to `.join` in `timeline` is marking the string as unsafe - maybe try altering it to:

```
def timeline(events)
  events.map do |event|
    render(:partial => "timeline_events/#{event.event_type}", :locals => {:event => event})
 end.join.html_safe
end
```

and see if that helps :-)